# Open the closest modal of jQuery clicked element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with having the **closest** modal pop up according to the a tag that was  **clicked**.  Not understanding why my jQuery is not working.

```
   <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="text-center"> gMaps XML </h2> 

   <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <p>this is a test of xml modal</p>
        </div>
      </div 
   </div>

      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p>
   <!-- makes above modal pop-up -->   <a href="#" class="code button white text-center" data-toggle="modal">View Code</a>
</div> <!-- END COL -->


<div class="col-md-3" >
   <h2 class="text-center"> Date JS </h2> 
 <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
       This is a test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore .</p>
 <!-- This clicked --> <a href="#" class="code button white text-center" data-toggle="modal" >View Code</a>
```

```
<script>
$("a.code").click(function(event){
   $(this).closest(".bs-example-modal-lg").modal("show");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome or IE to debug jQuery code

Comment: i did i'm not getting any errors

Comment: `$("a.code").click(function(event)` remove `a` just declare `.code`

Comment: Still no modal pops up.

Comment: give an space between a and .code

Comment: tried that but nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. I hope this will help you.

```
$("a.code").click(function(event){
   $(this).parent().find(".bs-example-modal-lg").modal("show");
  });
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L7ph0ndb/1/)**

Comment: Thank you thank you friend! Can I ask why closest() wasn't for this situation? 

ps. you got the vote!

Comment: because .closest() finds the nearest parent element, .bs-example-modal-lg is not a parent of it.